# Como ler um determinado número de linhas em C?

Tags: c

Este é o meu código que lê e procura a uma determinada palavra,

```
void* pthread_wordCounter(void* parameter){

    int count = 0;
    size_t linesize = 0;
    char *linebuf = 0;
    ssize_t linelenght=0;

    static const char filename[]= "pg76.txt";
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r"); //open file
    if (file!=NULL){
        while ((linelenght = getline(&linebuf, &linesize, file))>0) {
            if (strstr(linebuf,"elephant")!=NULL) //finds if there is the word on the line
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        fclose(file); //close file
        printf("The total amount of words is %d \n", count);
    }
    else{
        perror(filename);
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Como eu devo ler apenas 1000 linhas por vez (supondo que o arquivo tenha mais de 1000 linhas) e mandar este bloco de linhas para outra função que irá procurar a palavra?

Comment: Edite a pergunta e coloque o código que já fez para ficar mais fácil entendermos o teu problema.

Comment: O que isto tem a ver com *thread*?

Comment: Neste contexto não tem muito a ver, porém pode ser aplicado a um ambiente multithread

Comment: As *tags* devem ser usadas para identificar seu problema, não para dizer o que você você um dia vai fazer com isto.

Comment: `for(i=0; i<1000; i++){ lerlinha() }` ?

Answer (score 0):

Bom, para ler 1000 linhas deve-se primeiro pensar na crítica do caso em que a passada que vc for ler não possuir 1000 linhas.

Então sugiro que faça o seguinte no seu código:

```
void* pthread_wordCounter(void* parameter){

int count = 0;
size_t linesize = 0;
char *linebuf = 0;
ssize_t linelenght=0;
int counter = 0;

static const char filename[]= "pg76.txt";
FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r"); //open file
if (file!=NULL){
while((linelenght = getline(&linebuf, &linesize, file))>0){
        while ((linelenght = getline(&linebuf, &linesize, file))>0 && counter < 999) {
            counter++;
        }

    // AO FINAL ELE PODE FAZER ALGUMA COISA AQUI.

}
    fclose(file); //close file
    printf("The total amount of words is %d \n", count);
}
else{
    perror(filename);
}
return 0;
```

Note que eu adicionei duas coisas. Um contador interno que vai até 999 e um while externo que vai ler a primeira linha. O que está sendo feito é, o código vai tanto ler 1000 linhas e fazer o que você deseja no local indicado pelo comentário como vai parar quando o EOF chegar.

Espero ter ajudado, se estiver ainda difícil sugiro que especifique um pouco mais o problema para que a comunidade entenda.

=)